# Autobox and method overloading

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse. I have two methods:

```
public void doWork(long... parms){}

public void doWork(Object... parms){}
```

When I call

```
doWork(1,2,3);
```

Eclipse always shows it as being autoboxed to the `doWork(Object... parms)`. I really do want the `doWork(long... parms)` to be called when using only long values, as there is some extra processing being done.

Is there an order for using overloaded methods, and if so can I change it? So that the JVM "sees" the `doWork(long... parms)` before the `doWork(Object... parms)`.

Barring that, is there a way to turn off autoboxing? I'm a big boy, I can handle creating a `new Long()` when I need to...

I did do a work-around by having

```
public void doWorkL(long... parms){}
```

but it's ugly, and defeats the purpose of overloading.

Comment: what about `doWork(1L,2L,3L);`? There is no way to influence overload resolution or disable autoboxing (unless you want to switch back to Java 1.4)

Comment: `doWork(1L,2L,3L)` ?

Comment: Well, sometimes I have int mixed in, which are promoted as needed. Besides a primitive long also gets autoboxed

Comment: Which method is chosen is specified by the Java language specification (see [JLS 15.12.2.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)), not by Eclipse. In your example the methods have variable arity parameters (varargs) and a `long` primitive that can be converted via boxing to `Long` which is an `Object`. I guess most people (including me) will not be 100% sure which method is called by `doWork(1,2,3)`. So better avoid overloading here to improve readability.

Comment: I realize that Eclipse does not rule this, and that it is the JVM. I was just hoping that the more "correct" method would be used, that is the one which does not require extra JVM processing. Thanks all.

Comment: @BigGuy The selection which method of the two overloaded methods is called is done by the compiler, not at runtime. So there is no extra JVM processing here.

Comment: You're right of course. The IDE hides so much of the manual labor I had to do when I started, needing to run an editor, then a compiler, then a linker. Now it just magically happens, cross references in different files are resolved, etc. As you type yet...